# Struggling to switch between databases at runtime with Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to change which database is used at runtime (like from H2 to MySQL and back). Is it also possible to make both of them be used simultaneously (meaning whatever data is saved in both databases, whenever a repository is saved to use what appears to be the correct terminology or at least the convention)?

I tried so many different things, but my knowledge of Spring Boot is very limited.

My attempts all revolved around trying to change `spring.profiles.active=h2` to `spring.profiles.active=mysql` and vice versa, as in what's in the `application.properties` file, but within the code.

I'm not necessarily looking for a way that's similar to what I've been trying.

Could someone please help me figure out how to do this?

Any input would be GREATLY appreciated!

**P.S.**
For what it's worth, the code I'm working with is here ( https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic ).

Comment: Why? As those are different databases and different SQL dialects they don't translate 1-to-1, so only switching the database won't work, yu would also need to reconfigure Hibernate for instance (not just the dialect, the whole metadata in memory, meaning a restart). All in all it looks like you are trying something that you shouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Basically, I'm doing this because I'm trying to learn how to perform a live database migration (where both databases could potentially store data very differently). How do you think that should be tackled? Edit: I was thinking of doing stuff like somehow connecting to one database, storing the datum in a variable, switching to the other database and then saving that variable's data into that other database, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check Spring Cloud config, it is the mechanism to configure your app at run time.
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/